# Excel duplicate ever 10 rows of data and then reverse order

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of numbers 1 through 20. How can I make it so the first 10 rows of the series in order, then the next 10 rows are 1-10 in reverse order. Then do that every 10 rows of data.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to work on this, however in terms of readability, one can use the following. The following formula shown below doesn't require recursive `LAMBDA()` helper functions, as well as it is quite **succinct** and works well as per the **given data in OP**. That said:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(α, WRAPCOLS(B1:B20,10), TOCOL(VSTACK(α,SORT(α,,-1)),2,1))
```

---

Or, The following is more dynamic than the above, because if you have more than `20` rows and then using `SORT()` to sort every **index column** by descending order. Lastly to `VSTACK()` with the original one, and `TOCOL()` to convert into single array. Note the use of `2` and `1`  where `2` **ignores errors** while `1` to **scan by columns**. `2` I have used, not necessarily it has to be always even number of rows, it can be an odd one.

---

```
=LET(α, WRAPCOLS(B1:B50,10), TOCOL(VSTACK(α,SORT(α,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(α)),-1)),2,1))
```

---

- Using `WRAPCOLS()` converting a **one-dimensional** array into a **two-dimensional** array.
- Using `SORT()` function to sort in **descending order**.
- Using `VSTACK()` **appending** the original array with the sorted array.
- Using `TOCOL()` converting the array into a **single column**.

---

**Note:** *The given formula works well with the posted series of numbers in OP. If there is something else, then this might need some changes*.

---

**Another alternative method:**

```
=LET(
     α, WRAPCOLS(B1:B20,10), 
     TOCOL(VSTACK(α, CHOOSEROWS(α, SEQUENCE(ROWS(α),,10,-1))),2,1))
```

---

The above formula posted should work in all scenarios, since it doesn't depend on the `SORT()` function like the first method.

---

Answer (score 0):

This creates an array of row numbers then the INDEX returns the value at that row:

```
=LET(
    z,A1:A20,
    x,SEQUENCE(10),
    y,VSTACK(x,10-x+1),
    g,DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(z)/10,,0),LAMBDA(r,t,VSTACK(r,y+10*t))),1),
    INDEX(z,g))
```

- z is the range of values
- x creates a sequence from 1 to 10
- y stacks the x on top of the inverse (10 to 1)
- g adds the next grouping on the bottom of that, this is expandable as it finds the number of entries in Z and divides it by 10.
- Then we use INDEX to return the values on the relative row numbers in the group.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be

```
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(10),
     x,VSTACK(a,SORT(a,,-1)),
VSTACK(x,x+10))
```

You could also combine it with index
`=LET(x,SEQUENCE(10),y,VSTACK(x,SORT(x,,-1)),INDEX(B1:B20,VSTACK(y,y+10)))`